# Taking Values inputted into Excel Cells and using them in vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to find an answer to this question, and maybe I just do not understand coding very well, or the functions people are putting are too complex for me to understand.

I am using a more complex function, but for an example I would like to calculate Volume of an ideal gas (1 mole) based on different values of temp and pressure, so the equation is PV=nRT. I am wondering how do I take constant value inputs from excel cells, like A1 for Temperature, and A2 for Pressure, and input them in vba coding so that it is robust enough to be able to change those constant values, in order to find different volumes.

I know how to name cells, and define constants using name manager, but as far as calling those cell values into the functions in vba code, I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, in a standard module, define the function (in this example for volume):

```
Public Function BoyleVolume(Pressure As Double, Amount As Double, Temperature As Double) As Double
    BoyleVolume = 8.314 * Amount * Temperature / Pressure
End Function
```

and in the worksheet, use it like:

**=BoyleVolume(A1,B1,C1)**

put your parameters in A1, B1, and C1

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess I didn't realize it was this simple :)

Comment: It is basically a very similar approach to what you would use in a worksheet formula...........Have a Great Day!